# Append an element to a list while simultaneously deleting all duplicates

Tags: list-manipulation

I know the answer to the main question can be done using two separate commands but is there something like

```
           AppendTo[list,elem, Cond -> Noduplicates]
```

Comment: Can you not write your own `appendTo` and in it, check if the element is already there before adding it? something like `appendTo[lisin_List, x_] := 
 Module[{lis = lisin}, 
  If[Not[MemberQ[lis, x]], AppendTo[lis, x], lis]]` You can use `Union` to remove all duplicates as in `Union@AppendTo[lis, x]` I do not see how to do it in one call as someone has to check somewhere?

Comment: Maybe not efficient, but cute: `Keys@Append[AssociationThread[list -> True], elem -> True]` (probably doesn't work for all types of lists, tho).  There's also `Union[list, {elem}]`, though it will sort -- you probably thought of that.

Comment: No, I don't think so.  Associations have it built into how they manage keys, though.  So if `assoc = AssociationThread[list -> True]`, then `assoc[elem] = True` won't create a duplicate entry and will be very fast. And `Keys@assoc` give the current value of the list.  However, `assoc` takes considerably more memory than `list`, but if `list` is not large, this should not be a concern.

Comment: you may try `Append[list,elem] // DeleteDuplicates` , but notice there is not duplicates in list.

Comment: I'd recommend a combination of [`Sow`/`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressions.html#8044) during execution and [`DeleteDuplicates`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html) for post-processing. In general, `AppendTo` is not a great way of constructing lists.

Comment: Do you want duplicates in the initial list to be deleted, or for those to be left alone?

Comment: Output of AppendTrim[ {1,2,1,4,5,6}, 5 ] would be {1,2,4,5,6}

Comment: Maybe `appendTrim[x_List, y_]:= DeleteDuplicates[Sequence@@@{x,y}]`?

Comment: `With[{unique=DeleteDuplicates@list},If[MemberQ[list,elem],unique,Append[unique,elem]]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
list=Union[list,{elem}]
```

but this sorts the list.

Comment: Also mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264708/append-an-element-to-a-list-while-simultaneously-deleting-all-duplicates/264717#comment659661_264708)

Comment: I want this. Can someone also quickly say how to find the union of N (N is a variable) sets described by a variable index j : U[j] . In other words, Union[ U[j],{j,1,N} ]

Comment: This seems to work :  Union[Flatten[Table[U[j], {j, 1, N}]]]

Comment: If U is a list (not a function), and you want all elements of U, you can write: Union@@U, or for all elements to n (N is defined in Mathematica) you can write Union@@U[[;;n]]

Answer (score 9):

You are looking for the typical ease of use and high-level thinking that encapsulation brings to the mix. Using an OrderedHashSet datastructure:

```
ds = CreateDataStructure["OrderedHashSet"];
```

Numbers from 1-10 are "inserted"; the ordered is preserved.

```
Table[ds["Insert", i], {i, 1, 10}]
```

As a continuation of the example, lets append the following primes, without duplicates insertion and while preserving order using the "Union" method:

```
Table[Prime[i], {i, 1, 20}]
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, \
> 67, 71}
> ```

```
ds["Union", Table[Prime[i], {i, 1, 20}]]

Normal[ds]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, \
> 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71}
> ```

The "Complement" method will remove entries:

```
ds["Complement", Table[Prime[i], {i, 5, 10}]]
```

The `Normal` command shows that `{11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29}` have been removed.

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, \
> 59, 61, 67, 71}
> ```

---

```
ds["Visualization"]
```

[image]

The speed will be slower compared to native or compiled list operations, but this is an OOP way of thinking about it. There are additional "methods" that this data structure accepts.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the `elem` at the end of the (new) list and nowhere else in the list, try this

```
Append[DeleteCases[list,#],#]& [elem]
```

For example,

```
Append[DeleteCases[Range[5],#],#]& [3]   (* {1, 2, 4, 5, 3} *)
```

Since this method does not use `Union` or `DeleteDuplicates` it does not have the side effect of deleting other elements that are not `elem`.  To illustrate, appending a "3" does not delete the duplicated "1" in the following:

```
list = { 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5 };                                                                                          
elem = 3;                                                                                                             
Append[DeleteCases[list,#],#]& [elem]   (* {1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since V 13.1 we can also use `DeleteElements`:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5};
x = 3;

Append[x] @ DeleteElements[list, {x}]
```

{1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3}